# IOS Swift TimeLine Twitter obtener texto

Tags: json, ios, swift, twitter

Tengo que mostrar el contenido de unos tweets de determinadas cuentas de Twitter, muestro el TimeLine del usuario que le paso sin problemas a través de Fabric y TwitterKit. El problema es que esos tweets los tengo que almacenar en una base de datos, el texto, las Urls asociadas y algo más de información, por tanto no quiero que me los muestre por pantalla, quiero obtener esa información.

Con el siguiente código muestro el TimeLine de Twitter en la pantalla:

```
func mostrarTimeLine() {
    let client = TWTRAPIClient()
    self.dataSource = TWTRUserTimeLineDataSource(screenName: "cuentaTwitter", apiClient: client)
}
```

He probado a acceder a metodos del dataSource para intentar obtener el texto pero no he solucionado nada.

También he probado a descargarme un JSON con toda la información para luego parsearlo, pero he probado funciones de este tipo sin resultado, no se muy bien como definir la cadena de conexión para autentificarme con el usuario y no me devuelva que no estoy loggeada.

```
func obtener() {
    let txtrRequest = Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.URLRquestWithMethod("GET", URL: "https://userstream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/sample.json", parameters: nil, error: nil)
    let urlConnection = NSURLConnection(request: txtrRequest, delegate: self)
    urlConnection?.start()
}
```

No sé como hacerlo, he dado mil vueltas a las funciones que ofrece pero no doy con la solución. Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme.

Estoy con una aplicación desarrollada en IOS con Swift.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el **[recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)** y lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. Por favor revisa [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78)

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a [es.so]. ¿Podrías agregar tu código con lo que intentaste hasta ahora, incluso si está incompleto o no funcione? El sitio no es un sustituto de Google, por lo que te recomendaría agregar qué investigaste y qué intentaste. La idea es que las preguntas tengan un [mcve]. Encontrarás el enlace para [edit] al pie de tu pregunta.